# How to convert Google iOS Sign-In single page sample AppDelegate.h protocol -> to a segue to LoginPage ViewController AppDelegate.swift protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, google-apps-script

Google's Sign-In sample on GitHub [SignInSampleForPod.xcworkspace](https://github.com/google/GoogleSignIn-iOS/) creates a single page sign-in using the AppDelegate.h SignInViewController.m etc protocol.

However many apps, such as mine, prefer to segue to a Login Page only when a user makes a choice requiring verification. I just want the basic Google Profile info and authentication token.

I have the Google iOS ClientID configured enough so a segue to my LoginPage.swift shows the Google Sign-In button via AppDelegate.swift:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(
_ app: UIApplication,
open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
) -> Bool {
var handled: Bool 
handled = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(url)
if handled {
  return true
}
// Handle other custom URL types.
// If not handled by this app, return false.
return false
}

func application(
_ application: UIApplication,
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
) -> Bool {
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.restorePreviousSignIn { user, error in
  if error != nil || user == nil {
    // Show the app's signed-out state.
  } else {
    // Show the app's signed-in state.
  }
}
return true
}
```

And LoginPage.swift:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
let signInConfig = GIDConfiguration.init(clientID: "foo-bar85.apps.googleusercontent.com")
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: signInConfig, presenting: self) { user, error in
      guard error == nil else { return }
      guard let user = user else { return }

      let emailAddress = user.profile?.email

      let fullName = user.profile?.name
      let givenName = user.profile?.givenName
      let familyName = user.profile?.familyName

      let profilePicUrl = user.profile?.imageURL(withDimension: 320)
  }
```

[image: Segue to Login Page]

So my question is what is the AppDelegate.swift Google Sign-In code for the fields shown below to display the basic profile info:

```
    // Show the app's signed-out state.
  } else {
    // Show the app's signed-in state.
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not able to understand your problem clearly.
But I am trying to answer based on my understanding.

You can create a class (GoogleLoginManager) for all google login related stuff and create a button in UI then call this method (signIn) from button action.

```
@IBAction func googleButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    
    GoogleLoginManager.shared.signIn(controller: self) { (profile) in
        print("GoogleLogin profile : \(String(describing: profile.name)), \(String(describing: profile.email))")
        
    } onFailure: { (error) in
        print("GoogleLogin error : \(String(describing: error.localizedDescription))")
    }
}
```

import Foundation
import GoogleSignIn

class GoogleLoginManager: SocialLogin {

```
fileprivate var onSuccess : success?
fileprivate var onFailure : failure?

static let shared = GoogleLoginManager()
private override init() { }

func signIn(controller: UIViewController, onSuccess : @escaping success, onFailure : @escaping failure) {
    
    self.onSuccess = onSuccess
    self.onFailure = onFailure
    
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().presentingViewController = controller
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    
    // Automatically sign in the user.
    // GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.restorePreviousSignIn()
}

func signOut() {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
}
```

}

extension GoogleLoginManager : GIDSignInDelegate {

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
            print("The user has not signed in before or they have since signed out.")
        }
        else if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.canceled.rawValue {
            print("user canceled the sign in request")
        }
        else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        self.onFailure?(error)
        return
    }
    var profile =  SocialProfileModel.init(user: user)
    profile.loginSuccess = true
    self.onSuccess?(profile)
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {
    // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
    print("GIDSignIn : didDisconnectWith")
    
}
```

}

Comment: You can checkout full code here : https://github.com/singh46/SocialLogin-iOS

Comment: I've edited my question thinking the minimum I need to add is some standard code to the "Show the app's signed-in state" field.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to modify my above AppDelegate.swift slightly - adding a standard UIbutton linked to the following action - gets the profile info:

```
 @IBAction func LogInButtonTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
  GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: signInConfig, presenting: self) { user, error in
      guard error == nil else { return }
      guard let user = user else { return }

      let emailAddress = user.profile?.email

      let fullName = user.profile?.name
      let givenName = user.profile?.givenName
      let familyName = user.profile?.familyName

      let profilePicUrl = user.profile?.imageURL(withDimension: 320)
    print("GoogleLogin profile : \(String(describing: user.profile?.name)), \(String(describing: user.profile?.email))")
  }
}
```